# getting the matching string when calling a regexp from a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

in a bash script, I have :

```
mkv="xxxx E05 xxxx"

if [[ $mkv =~ E[0-9]{2} ]] ; then echo FOUND; fi
```

good. this tells me if $mkv matches against E[0-9]{2}, but this is not what I want.

I want to get the matching string (i.e. 05 in my example)

I put a reference () in my regexp, hoping I'd be able to get it later, but I could not.

I tried :

```
if [[ $mkv =~ E([0-9]{2}) ]] ; then echo FOUND $1; fi

if [[ $mkv =~ E([0-9]{2}) ]] ; then echo FOUND \1; fi
```

etc... but all of them failed

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BASH_REMATCH` array to get the parts that matched:

```
if [[ $mkv =~ E([0-9]{2}) ]] ; then echo FOUND ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ; fi
```

`${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` will contain the whole/full match (`Exx`), `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` the first captured group (only the digits here).

Comment: Just to add, Here `REMATCH` is not *re-match* rather *regular expression match*.